# Weird behavior of DrawText under Win64

Tags: delphi, drawtext

I have a listbox with one item 'ABC'.

The following code works fine under Win32:

```
h := DrawText(ListBox1.Canvas.Handle, PChar(ListBox1.Items[0]), -1, R, DT_CALCRECT);
```

After that line `h = 19`, which is correct.
Using the same code under Win64 returns 0, e.g. `h = 0`

SysErrorMessage(GetLastError) returns "The operation completed successfully"

Now if I modify the code this way, it works both on Win32 and Win64.

```
s := ListBox1.Items[0];
h := DrawText(ListBox1.Canvas.Handle, PChar(s), -1, R, DT_CALCRECT);
```

After this change `h = 19` on Win32 and Win64. Any ideas why a temporary variable is needed under Win64?

Comment: Which Delphi version and what is the size of `R`?

Comment: What you seem to be attempting can be solved with h := ListBox1.ItemHeight if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm using Delphi 11.2, R is defined as TRect

Comment: May be caused by a different order of parameter evaluation in Win32 and Win64. I had a similar problem described and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358110/why-does-a-call-to-getdibits-fail-on-win64

Comment: Parameter order doesn't matter here. With the original one liner code the compiler does need to assign the string to a temporary local. If the code is failing then I guess that isn't happening. It's very likely a bug in specific versions of the compiler because as an XE7 user I am reasonably confident that this works as expected. I'd submit a bug report.

Comment: I also think that it has nothing to do with parameter evaluation. The call to that function is made in a button OnClick event and at that time the ListBox is fully visible and its Handle is allocated. Indeed the ListBox.Items.Get (TListBoxStrings) uses SendMessage to return the string.